# How to assign a response from AXIOS to an array in state of functional component(React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch the array from my result.data which is returned by axios.post and assign it to the sate in functional component.
Below is the code sample.
Thank you in advance.

I have created a state with an empty array in a functional component using useState like below.

```
const [pdsummaryState, setpdsummaryState] = useState({
  Data: {
         Results:[]
        }
 });
```

I am trying to assign the array which is returned by axios.post to the state like below

```
 axios.post(config.api.invokeUrl + '/query', queryData)
    .then((res)=> {
     console.log(res.data);  
     setpdsummaryState(res.data);     
 })
```

The result in res.data is as below.

output of `console.log(res.data);`

[image]

I am trying to assign the array which is in Results to the state.

Full code is as below.

```
   const Home = props => {   
         useEffect(() => {
          appInit(); 
          makePostRequest();
        }, []);

       const [pdsummaryState, setpdsummaryState] = useState({
          Data: {
            Results:[]
          }
         });

       async function makePostRequest() {
          axios.post(config.api.invokeUrl + '/query', queryData)
             .then((res)=> {
                 console.log(res.data);  
                 setpdsummaryState(res.data);     
          })    
     }
  }
```

I expect to get the array from the response to the state array and iterate it to display the data in a table.

```
setpdsummaryState(res.data); 
console.log(pdsummaryState);
```

The above is returning an empty array. 
It is not getting assigned to the state for some reason and can I have just an array in my state instead of

```
Data: { Results:[] }
```

just

```
Results:[]
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?  Code looks ok to me.

Comment: Data stored correctly in state, you can use `pdsummaryState.Data.Results.map(data=>console.log(data))` for your iteration.

Comment: What difficulty you are facing?

Comment: setPickdetailssummaryState(res.data); 
console.log(pickdetailssummaryState); 
This is returning empty array. 
It is not getting assigned to the state for some reason and can I have just an array in my state instead of 

Data: { Results:[] } 
just 
Results:[]

Comment: In your full code you have `setpdsummaryState`, where is `setPickdetailssummaryState`?

Comment: Ravi. My bad. It was a typo. I have updated it. Yet to get the solution.

Comment: Ravi I tried your answer but still not assigning to the state.
The state is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is async and it execute in a batch inside a scope. You are updating the state that is correct but in next line when you are doing console till that time state is not updated so it is showing the default or old value.you can use async and await.
If you use class component, this.setState had one callback option which will solve this problem. But as you are using useState hook that is not available by default but there is another library for useState callback please google it.
Otherwise after updating console it out side the useEffect hooks.You can get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly have an array in state,

```
const [pdsummaryState, setpdsummaryState] = useState([]);
```

You can set the data like this,

```
async function makePostRequest() {
   axios.post(config.api.invokeUrl + '/query', queryData)
     .then((res)=> {
         console.log(res.data);  
         setpdsummaryState(res.data.Data.Results); //Get only array
         //This will never give you the updated state, because setState is async
         console.log(pdsummaryState);      
     })    
}
```

You can directly iterate your state like,

```
{
pdsummaryState.map(data=>console.log(data.result))  //check the console and you will get data.
}
```

Read more about [setState](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

Comment: I tried your answer but still not assigning to the state. The state is still empty.
I also tried by JSON.stringify(res.data.Data.Results) but no luck still.

Comment: After doing `setpdsummaryState(res.data.Data.Results);` your component is re-rendered or not?

Comment: To check your state is updated or not do this, `useEffect(()=>{console.log(pdsummaryState)},[pdsummaryState])`